# How to specify timeout setting for IBM Cloud Functions action in manifest?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

I am trying to [deploy an action for IBM Cloud Functions using a manifest file](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-deploy). I know that it is possible to [change the value for the timeout setting](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/openwhisk?topic=cloud-functions-cli-plugin-functions-cli#cli_action_create) using `--timeout LIMIT` in the CLI. How can it be done in the manifest file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the specification for the [OpenWhisk / IBM Cloud Functions manifest](https://github.com/apache/openwhisk-wskdeploy/blob/master/specification/html/spec_actions.md#actions). It is possible to set **limits** for an action. One of the supported limits is **timeout**.

Setting the timeout to the maximum allowed value could look like this (based on the provided example in the docs):

```
my_awesome_action:
  version: 1.0
  function: src/js/action.js
  runtime: nodejs@>0.12<6.0
  inputs:
    not_awesome_input_value:
      description: Some input string that is boring
      type: string
  outputs:
    awesome_output_value:
      description: Impressive output string
      type: string
  limits:
    timeout: 600000
```